# Find duplicates by partial string match

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table mytable that has an `ID` with leading zeros and a "duplicate" without leading zeros. i.e. I have 2 rows one is `456` and the other is `000456`.The max data length for ones with leading zeros is 6 characters. I need to return the matches based of the fact that one has leading zeros, and the other does not.

I have tried:

```
SELECT constituent_id,  RIGHT('000000'+ISNULL(id,''),6) as missingbutpadded    
from mytable 
where id is not null and id not like '0%'
```

this returns the first column without leading zeros and the the same values in the second column with leading zeros up to 6 characters. How do I do a match to ones with leading zeros?

Here is the table right now:
mytable

```
|system_id| id   |first_name |last_name 
|1        |000456|James      | Smith    
|2        |456   |James      |Smith 
|3        |000555|Mary       |Carl  
|4        |555   |mary       |Carl
```

Expected_Results

```
system_id |id    |matchedto |first_name |last_name
2         | 456  |000456    |James      |smith
4         | 555  |000555    |Mary       |Carl
```

Comment: The lesson here is don't store your numeric id's in an alphanumeric column.

Comment: Just `CAST(YourColumn AS INT )` ?

Comment: You are unclear. You say you have 2 rows, but the query shows 2 columns. Plus also what are you trying to see in results? Both, just one, just one based on some preference?

Comment: (Sorry - first time posting a question and Iforget to hit ctrl + enter)

 I'm using SQL Server 2013. 
@Dmitriy:
ID
000456
456
I would like the results to contain;
MathedIDs,matchedto
000456,456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select table1.Id as MatchId, table2.Id as MatchedId
from yourtable table1
inner join yourtable table2 ON Convert(int,table1.Id)=Convert(int,table2.Id)
Where table1.id<>table2.id and table2.id like '0%'
```

That will do what you want.

Here it is with a test

```
create table #mytable(id varchar(50))
insert into #mytable(id) values ('45'), ('0056'),('0045')

select table1.Id as MatchId, table2.Id as MatchedId
from #mytable table1
inner join #mytable table2 ON Convert(int,table1.Id)=Convert(int,table2.Id)
Where table1.id<>table2.id and table2.id like '0%'
```

(3 row(s) affected)
MatchId                                            MatchedId

---

45                                                 0045

(1 row(s) affected)

Comment: That does not return the expected results. I cannot figure out a syntax for a partial match in the where clause. So I want the result to be in one row vs. 2 rows. i.e. we made a match because ID 456 exists as a separate row with leading zeros
matchedIDS,matchedto
000456,456

Comment: It certainly returns what you want, I just tested it. the like '0%' is doing partial match    

 create table #mytable(id varchar(50))
insert into #mytable(id) values ('45'), ('0056'),('0045')

select table1.Id as MatchId, table2.Id as MatchedId
from #mytable table1
inner join #mytable table2 ON Convert(int,table1.Id)=Convert(int,table2.Id)
Where table1.id<>table2.id and table2.id like '0%'

Comment: @Dimitry: Thank you, this works - not sure what I did the first time i tested it.